# Common language effect size / Probability of Superiority with Measurement Error

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

The setting is comparing two independent groups represented by random variables $X$, and $Y$. The common language effect size / probability of superiority / relative effect ... is defined as $p(X,Y)=P(X<Y)+0.5P(X=Y)$.

I am wondering what happens if we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are generated from latent variables such that

$$X=X_L + \epsilon_X, Y=Y_L + \epsilon_Y$$

with all random variables being i.i.d., $X_L$, $Y_L$ following arbitrary distributions, $\epsilon_X, \epsilon_Y$ representing error, lets say $E(\epsilon_X)=E(\epsilon_Y)=0$ and both distributions are symmetric.

Specifically, I wonder under what conditions $p(X_L,Y_L)\geq p(X,Y)$ holds. This should be the case if all distributions are normal. In this case, $p(X,Y)$ is a monotonic function of Cohen's d (see [Two methods of converting Cohen's d to CL (common language effect size / Probability of Superiority) yield different results?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517216/two-methods-of-converting-cohens-d-to-cl-common-language-effect-size-probabi)). Adding normally distributed errors to $X_L$ and $Y_L$ leads to increasing the variance but does not change the mean difference. Thus Cohen's d comparing $X$ and $Y$ is smaller than for $X_L$ and $Y_L$. Thus in this case, $p(X_L,Y_L)\geq p(X,Y)$ holds.

I tried other conditions in R and could not yet produce a counter-example. Thus might it even always hold?